# Do CDNs (such as MSFT and Google) act on the referrer header sent by clients?

Tags: web-development, javascript, microsoft, google, seo

Will my site be automatically indexed, or search ranking affected based on my use (or non use) of the Google/MSFT CDN?

My clients will be sending them the referrer header which I may or may not want included in search results.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your URLs indexed in search engines then use a [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

If you don't want your URLs accessible by a random person who knows it exists, then use authentication.

If you don't want a random person to know that your URL exists, then don't put it on the Internet. If it's on the Internet then you have to consider that anyone could find it.